# PresentViewController Hiding UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

My Views

- ViewController: home view, UINavigationController
- IntroViewController: intro view, **no** UINavigationController

At the beginning of the code I used a little check to see if the user has seen the intro view before, if not, I used the following code to get from `ViewController` to `IntroViewController`:

```
IntroViewController *introViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IntroViewController"];
            [self presentViewController:introViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Everything worked out fine, the intro played well, then upon going back to `ViewController` with the following code, the UINavigationBar and the UIToolbar disappeared, but the content of the view is still visible:

```
ViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
            [self presentViewController:homeViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I feel like I'm missing something small, I am just unable to find it. Can anyone please provide me with some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the fact that you are presenting view controller as "it is".
I bet you don't have `UINavigationController` that controls your HomeViewController in the Storyboard, right?
And, of course, IntroViewController does have a `UINavigationController` in it (or it is "**controlled**" by `UINavigationController`), right?

The solution would be to add `UINavigationController` that will manage your HomeViewController. In that case everything will work out just fine.

But don't forget that you'll have 2 different instances of `UINavigationController` in your app from that moment.

When controller is being presented, its view is being *added* to **view** hierarchy, and not to navigation stack.

From `-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]` documentation:

> This method sets the presentedViewController property to the specified view controller, resizes that view controller’s view and then adds the view to the view hierarchy

For reference, please read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a).

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get back to the controller that presented you, you don't present another instance of that controller, which is what you're doing. You dismiss yourself with,

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

The presentviewcontroller methos replace the whole view so if you have any navigationbar or toolbar.. it will not be displayed.

If you want to go back to the previos view.. you should use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

if for any reason ... you need to create a new instance of that view.. you should create a new navigation controller set the destination view controller as the rootviewcontroller... and present the navigationcontroller. This will make the navigationBar appear again.

GL HF